# Problemas para ejecutar función postgres en phpPgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Tengo un conjunto de funciones creadas en postgres, voy a tomar como ejemplo esta:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.dia_semana(fecha date)
  RETURNS double precision AS
  $BODY$
  select extract(dow from fecha) 
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

funciona perfecto en PgAdmin III local, pero al ejecutar en phpPgAdmin alojado en un servidor Cpanel genera un error, el cual indica que la variable que se pasa como parámetro no existe:

```
select dia_semana('2019-07-02');
```

[image: Error en phpPgAdmin]

En cambio, en el PgAdmin III que tengo local si funciona perfectamente:

[image: Función local]

Dejo algunos datos tecnicos: la version del pg en el phpPgAdmin es la 8.4.20 y la versión del PgAdmin III es la 9.5.

todas las consultas sin funciones de todas las tablas trabajan bien en las dos bases de datos, pero las que tengan funciones me presentan el mismo error en el phpPgAdmin, por favor si alguien me podría ayudar en encontrar el problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola tu problema consiste en que estas usando una versión muy antigua de PostgresQL (8.4.2) y las funciones en `SQL` permiten referenciar a los parámetros por su nombre desde la version 9.2 (por eso te funciona en 9.5), puedes chequear la [documentación](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/release-9-2.html#AEN115236)

Si quieres resolverlo en este caso debes usar la referencia posicional en vez de la referencia por nombre para que sea compatible con las versiones antiguas, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.dia_semana(fecha date)
  RETURNS double precision AS
  $BODY$
  select extract(dow from $1) 
  $BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, era eso